# How to fetch data from database table on PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

I have created one IMS in that I am trying to fetch data from one table from the database and display it in drop-down form to another page.
In the database, I have created one table named a party in that table one column named party_name is available and I have to fetch that column data to my order page. Below is my Code. If anyone knows a solution than please help.

```
<select name="party[]" style="width:100%;" required>
   <?php
     $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM partys");
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['party_name'];?></option>
   <?php
    }
   ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Basic mysql. Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Comment: post some code where you face problem.

Comment: 1.What is the problem here? 2. what is the output of `var_dump($partys);` (post in question)? 3. I am unable to see any DB connection and record fetching code here.

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: what about that answer below; did that not work for you?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: [mysql extension is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli), you should use at least mysqli_*:

Secondly: try the below example, replacing the database connection string variables with your database credentials:

```
<select name="party[]" style="width:100%;" required>
  <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
<?php
  $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'userName', 'password', 'databaseName')
    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM partys";
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['party_name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Still blank drop down is coming

Comment: Did you add your database connection credentials? What are the table columns called?

Comment: Can you cut and paste the EXACT table Name and the EXACT column names from that table?

Comment: It worked perfectly but right now issue i am facing is i unable to change value from drop down(in partys table 3 currently three records are available) by default it is selecting first value from table

Comment: Can you show me the HTML that comes back for the query?

Comment: Add this below the <select> tag: <option value="">-- Please select --</option> I edited my answer to include this

Comment: @RuchirShah - please accept my answer if you have come right

Comment: @RuchirShah - my pleasure, can you please accept my answer as the solution Thanks!